# i have to create an array of structs with a pointed array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

to do so i created a pointed array from a dimension given from the standard input, the i allocated memory for each struct in the array.
do this have any sense? how do i solve this?
EDIT since riga[x] is an int, how do i connect the struct with the array? EDIT 2 I need to create an array of structs and the dimension of the array is given in the standard input. Sorry if I'm not good with words, I'm fairly new to this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char c;
    int ni;
    double nr;
}dati;

int main () {

    int a,b,K;
    int *riga;

    printf("a b K\n");
    scanf ("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&K);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, K);

    riga= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*K);
    printf("insert %d valors",K);
    for (int k=0;k<K;k++)
            scanf("%d", &riga[k]);
    for(int p=0;p <K;p++)
            printf("%d\n", riga[p]);

    for (int x=0; x>K;x++)
            riga[x]=malloc(sizeof(dati));



    for (int i=0; i<K; i++){
            printf("insert data in line %d", i+1);
            scanf("%c %d %lf", riga[i].c, riga[i].ni, riga[i].nr);
    }

    for (int j=0; j<K;j++)
            printf("%c %d %lf\n", riga[j].c,riga[j].ni,riga[j].nr);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

it gives me a warning in line 28 "warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘void *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
"
and errors for printing the struct "error: request for member ‘c’ in something not a structure or union"

Comment: `riga[x]=malloc(sizeof(dati));` - `riga[x]` is an `int` and you are assigning it with a pointer

Comment: Also the loop condition`for (int x=0; x>K;x++)` does not make sense.

Comment: You have a `k` and a `K` variable? Please don't. This is how you alienate your co-workers. It's not worth the confusion.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. What is your intention?
If you want to create an array you can do the following:
`dati *myArray; myArray = malloc(sizeof (*myArray) * K)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable *riga* needs to be an array of *dati*. You also need to check that the calls to *scanf* are successful. To skip leading whitespace you need to add a space before `%c` in the format string. To make memory allocation easier I always use a macro function for that. Here is a solution:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NEW_ARRAY(pointer, length) \
    { \
        (pointer) = malloc(((size_t) length) * sizeof (pointer)[0]); \
        if ((pointer) == NULL) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Allocating memory failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    }

typedef struct {
    char c;
    int ni;
    double nr;
} dati;

int main(void)
{
    dati *riga;
    int K, n;

    printf("Number of lines: ");
    n = scanf("%d", &K);
    if ((n == 1) && (K > 0)) {
        NEW_ARRAY(riga, K);
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            printf("insert data in line %d: ", i + 1);
            n = scanf(" %c %d %lf", &riga[i].c, &riga[i].ni, &riga[i].nr);
            if (n != 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Character, integer and real number expected at line %d\n", i + 1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            printf("%c %d %lf\n", riga[i].c, riga[i].ni, riga[i].nr);
        }
        free(riga);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Non-negative integer expected\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using macro like NEW_ARRAY is usually an antipatter. I suggest adding a new function like 'malloc_or_die()'

Comment: @tstanisl Why is it an antipattern? I have used it successfully for several years. The nice thing about the macro is that you don't need to fiddle with sizeof; you just need to say how many elements you want. With an ordinary function, like malloc_or_die as you suggest, you need to pass the size in bytes.

Comment: There are a few issues here:
1) it look like a function but it modifies `riga` argument, thus it should take `&riga` as an argument
2) it evaluates `riga` two times, in case of pointer VLA, even 3 times
   though  using capitals helps to warn that it's a macro
3) needs `do { ... } while (0)` trick to fix eating else in `if (...) NEW_ARRAY(...); else ...`
4) it's cumbersome to use during initialization or inside expressions because one has to use two lines: `int *x; NEW_ARRAY(x, size);` while for other option it would be `int *x = malloc_or_die(size, sizeof *x);`

Comment: @tstanisl The macro defines a block so there should be now problem in the if-else statement in your example. The other problems don't show up if you avoid the antipattern of using expressions with side-effects and initialize variables as late as possible (to minimize variable live time).

Comment: if i use your code it works fine, but if i want to put the parte of NEW_ARRAY inside the main it doesn't work
i used "riga=malloc(sizeof(riga)[0]*((size_t)K));" if K=4, i insert the data in line 1 then goes to line 3 where i put other data and then it return data in line 1 in line 2 and data in line 3 in line 4

Comment: i didn't see the space before %c. thank you very much it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `int *riga`. So, your first two `for` loops will store the data. That is, `riga` is a pointer to a 1D array of `int`.

So, your first two `for` loops are okay.

---

But, in your third `for` loop you do:

```
 riga[x] = malloc(sizeof(dati));
```

You _dereference `riga`, so that is an `int` but you are assigning a *pointer*

---

`riga` is [again] a pointer to an `int` array and *not* a pointer to an array of your `struct`, so you can *not* do (e.g.):

```
riga[i].c
```

---

It is *unclear* what data you have or how you want to store it. There are two interpretations:

1. It appears that you want to input *two* separate arrays. First, a simple 1D array of `int` of length `K` that you call `riga`. And, a separate array of your `dati` struct, also of length `K`
2. You only want *one* array of your struct `dati` of length `K`

I've refactored the code [with some guesses] as to what you need.

I chose interpretation (1) because it's closest to your code. I renamed `riga` to `datarray` when it referred to your `dati` struct.

If you wanted (2), just remove the `riga` related code below.

I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Here is the adjusted code [with some annotations]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char c;
    int ni;
    double nr;
} dati;

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, K;

    printf("a b K\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &K);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, K);

    // this is interpretation (1) -- you want two separate arrays
#ifndef ONLY_ONE_ARRAY
#if 0
    int *riga = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * K);
#else
    int *riga = malloc(sizeof(*riga) * K);
#endif

    printf("insert %d valors", K);
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        scanf("%d", &riga[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        printf("%d\n", riga[i]);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: riga is an int pointer so this is invalid
#if 0
    for (int x = 0; x > K; x++)
        riga[x] = malloc(sizeof(dati));
#else
    dati *datarray = malloc(sizeof(*datarray) * K);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        printf("insert data in line %d", i + 1);
#if 0
        scanf("%c %d %lf", riga[i].c, riga[i].ni, riga[i].nr);
#else
        scanf("%c %d %lf", datarray[i].c, datarray[i].ni, datarray[i].nr);
#endif
    }

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        printf("%c %d %lf\n", riga[j].c, riga[j].ni, riga[j].nr);
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        printf("%c %d %lf\n", datarray[i].c, datarray[i].ni, datarray[i].nr);
#endif

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: i want to do the (2), i trid using your code witout the part (1) but it doesn't work